# After more than several static bodies player and everything moving so fast in box2d using libgdx

Tags: libgdx, game-physics, game-development, box2d

I am creating platformer game in box2d using libgdx. The problem is occurring as the more bodies are added, the speed keeps increasing of player. Jump and movement are very fast after that.

i have tried adjusted the simulation step but not working.

```
    bodyDef = new BodyDef() ;
    bodyDef.type    = this.type ;


    bodyDef.fixedRotation = false;

    bodyDef.position.set(x + parentNodeX , node.getY() + node.getHeight() / 2) ;

    body = Engine.world.createBody(bodyDef) ;

    shape = new PolygonShape() ;
    shape.setAsBox(node.getWidth() / 2, node.getHeight() / 2) ;

    fixtureDef = new FixtureDef() ;

    if(node.getName().equals("HeroBody"))
    {
        System.out.println("HeroBody SET");
        fixtureDef.density = 1f ;

        fixtureDef.restitution = 0.05f;
        fixtureDef.friction = 0.2f;
    }
    else
    {
        fixtureDef.density = 0.2f ;

        fixtureDef.isSensor = false ;
        fixtureDef.friction = 0.5f;
        fixtureDef.restitution = 0f;
    }

    fixtureDef.shape = shape ;

    body.createFixture(fixtureDef) ;

    body.setUserData(node.getName()) ;

    shape.dispose() ;
```

simulation :

```
    float delta = Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime() ;

   
    float frameTime = Math.min(delta, 0.25f);
    accumulator += frameTime; accumulator
    
    while (accumulator >= STEP_TIME) {
        Engine.world.step(1.0f/60.0f, 6, 2);
        accumulator -= STEP_TIME;
    }
```

Comment: Can you share yours code?

Comment: Jiří : code added.

Comment: I don't see any issue at first glance (except the syntax error caused by word `accumulator`). Maybe the issue is because you are calling simulation code multiple times or movement code is wrong?

Comment: No, actually when i execute game player suddenly drop very fast (like very fast gravity) without any movement using impulse etc. i dont know what is happening.

Comment: The drop should be caused by gravity which you set when creating the world `World world = new World(new Vector2(0, -10), true);` - 10m/s^2 on y axis. Or do you suspect the cause is something else?

Comment: yes, same as you mentioned.
world  = new World(new Vector2(0, -9.8f), true) ;
When I add fewer bodies, the speed slows down.

Comment: Jiří : Resolved, simulation update method looping multiple times. "As many bodies, that many loops." Thanks for your help.